# Trying to add a show/hide button, but overwritten by theme's javascript

Tags: javascript

Edit - I was able to find the js file and remove the hover-over effect.

I'm working on WP. 
I have an optin form that I need to show on click on a button. The functionality provided by the theme shows the form on hover-over but it's buggy and makes the user experience bad.

I have managed to add the button, but I don't know how to overwrite the current hover-over function.

Here's that I have

Javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function toggle(id) {
        var state = document.getElementById(id).style.display;
            if (state == 'block') {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
            }
        } 
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="nav_subscription" class="subscription_form clearfix">
<span id="subscribe_dd" class="contrast"><?php gb_e( 'Get the Latest Deals' ) ?><span><a href="#" onclick="toggle('subscription_form_wrap');">Toggle Div</a></spa>

</div><!-- #main_navigation --> 

    <div id="subscription_form_wrap" style="display:none;">
    <div class="optinbar_close" style="bottom: 202px; left: -10px;"></div>                           
    <p class="fillout2">Συμπλήρωσε την παρακάτω φόρμα και μπες στο club επικοινωνίας του Fitness Forum για να σου στείλουμε αμέσως με email το δώρο σου. Απλά, γράψε το όνομα και το email σου και κλίκαρε 'Στείλτε το δώρο μου'.</p>   


<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->                                    
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">                  

    </div>
</div><!-- #header_subscription.subscription_form -->
```

CSS

```
#subscription_form_wrap {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    background: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 34px;
    right: 0;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    font-size: 13px;
    }

#subscribe_dd {
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 17px;
    background-color: #999;
    width: 255px;
    height: 19px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    }

.optinbar_close {
    float: right;
    background: url(assets/images/close3.png) no-repeat;
    display: inline;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    }
```

Here's a [link] to the website.

I'm trying to fix the gray box on the navigation bar that writes: "Έχεις ήδη κερδίσει ένα δώρο!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you want, but instead of:

```
<span id="subscribe_dd" class="contrast">Έχεις ήδη κερδίσει ένα δώρο!<span>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle('subscription_form_wrap');">Toggle Div</a></spa>
```

You could try to wrap the span into the a href:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle('subscription_form_wrap');">
    <span id="subscribe_dd" class="contrast">Έχεις ήδη κερδίσει ένα δώρο!<span>
</a>
```

If you really want to use only Javascript, this also works:

```
<span id="subscribe_dd" class="contrast" onclick="toggle
    ('subscription_form_wrap')>Έχεις ήδη κερδίσει ένα δώρο!<span>
```

Didn't know what that tag

```
</spa>
```

was about though. ;)

Comment: Thank you Markus! I was actually able to find the js file and remove the hover over effect!

Comment: You're welcome. Now I understand what you wanted. ;) So I did correct another error of your page. Would be great if you upvote my answer tough. ;D